# Calculating calendar weeks from fiscal weeks

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

So I am really new to this and struggling with something, which I feel should be quite simple.

I have a Pandas Dataframe containing two columns: Fiscal Week (str) and Amount sold (int).

|  | Fiscal Week | Amount sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019031 | 24 |
| 1 | 2019041 | 47 |
| 2 | 2019221 | 34 |
| 3 | 2019231 | 46 |
| 4 | 2019241 | 35 |

My problem is the fiscal week column. It contains strings which describe the fiscal year and week . The fiscal year for this purpose starts on October 1st and ends on September 30th. So basically, 2019031 is the Monday (the 1 at the end) of the third week of October 2019. And 2019221 would be the 2nd week of March 2020.
The issue is that I want to turn this data into timeseries later. But I can't do that with the data in string format - I need it to be in date time format.

I actually added the 1s at the end of all these strings using

```
df['Fiscal Week']= df['Fiscal Week'].map('{}1'.format)
```

so that I can then turn it into a proper date:

```
df['Fiscal Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fiscal Week'], format="%Y%W%w")
```

as I couldn't figure out how to do it with just the weeks and no day defined.
This, of course, returns the following:

|  | Fiscal Week | Amount sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-21 | 24 |
| 1 | 2019-01-28 | 47 |
| 2 | 2019-06-03 | 34 |
| 3 | 2019-06-10 | 46 |
| 4 | 2019-06-17 | 35 |

As expected, this is clearly not what I need, as according to the definition of the fiscal year week 1 is not January at all but rather October.

Is there some simple solution to get the dates to what they are actually supposed to be?

Ideally I would like the final format to be e.g. 2019-03 for the first entry. So basically exactly like the string but in some kind of date format, that I can then work with later on. Alternatively, calendar weeks would also be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a data frame with fiscal dates of the form 'YYYYWW' where YYY = the calendar year of the start of the fiscal year and ww = the number of weeks into the year, you can convert to calendar dates as follows:

```
def getCalendarDate(fy_date: str):
    f_year = fy_date[0:4]
    f_week = fy_date[4:]
    fys = pd.to_datetime(f'{f_year}/10/01', format= '%Y/%m/%d')
    return fys + pd.to_timedelta(int(f_week), "W")
```

You can then use this function to create the column of calendar dates as follows:

```
df['Calendar Date]'] =  list(getCalendarDate(x) for x in df['Fiscal Week'].to_list())
```

Comment: I had trouble understanding all the list stuff in the second part but I think I've got it now - we're adding all the entries of the column "fiscal Week" into a list and then applying the function getCalendarDate to each of these entries. These are put into another list (?) which is then attached to the dataframe as a new column "Calendar Date". I wouldn't have thought of all this on my own! Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, the df['Fiscal Week'] is a pd Series and the .to_list()n converts this to a list of values, which are then stepped through and converted to a Calendar date.  The for x in fiscal date list creates a generator which is then used to build the final list and as you say the final list is then added to the df as a new column